# Does Google support 2-Legged OAuth 2.0 for IMAP?

Tags: oauth-2.0, imap, gmail-imap, 2-legged

Does Google support 2-Legged OAuth 2.0 for IMAP? I know Google supports 3-legged OAuth 2.0 for IMAP, but I can't find any documentation for  2-Legged OAuth 2.0 for IMAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and the relevant documentation can be found at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth#GoogleAppsOAuth and examples are provided
on https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount